# Linear regression for each category of a variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, categories, correlation

Let's say I'm working with the `iris` dataset in R:

```
data(iris)

summary(iris)
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   : 4.300   Min.   : 2.000   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   : 0.100  
 1st Qu.: 5.100   1st Qu.: 2.800   1st Qu.: 1.600   1st Qu.: 0.300  
 Median : 5.800   Median : 3.000   Median : 4.350   Median : 1.300  
 Mean   : 5.843   Mean   : 3.057   Mean   : 3.758   Mean   : 1.199  
 3rd Qu.: 6.400   3rd Qu.: 3.300   3rd Qu.: 5.100   3rd Qu.: 1.800  
 Max.   : 7.900   Max.   : 4.400   Max.   : 6.900   Max.   : 2.500  
       Species  
 setosa    : 50  
 versicolor: 50  
 virginica : 50
```

I want to perform a linear regression where `Petal.Length` is the dependent variable, and `Sepal.Length` is the independent variable. How can I, in R, perform this regression for each `Species` category at once, getting values of P, R² and F for each test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `by`.

```
by(iris, iris$Species, \(x) summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, x)))
# iris$Species: setosa
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = x)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.40856 -0.08027 -0.00856  0.11708  0.46512 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)   0.80305    0.34388   2.335   0.0238 *
#   Sepal.Length  0.13163    0.06853   1.921   0.0607 .
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.1691 on 48 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.07138, Adjusted R-squared:  0.05204 
# F-statistic:  3.69 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 0.0607
# 
# --------------------------------------------------------- 
#   iris$Species: versicolor
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = x)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.68611 -0.22827 -0.04123  0.19458  0.79607 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   0.18512    0.51421   0.360     0.72    
# Sepal.Length  0.68647    0.08631   7.954 2.59e-10 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.3118 on 48 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.5686,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5596 
# F-statistic: 63.26 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 2.586e-10
# 
# --------------------------------------------------------- 
#   iris$Species: virginica
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = x)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.68603 -0.21104  0.06399  0.18901  0.66402 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   0.61047    0.41711   1.464     0.15    
# Sepal.Length  0.75008    0.06303  11.901  6.3e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.2805 on 48 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7469,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7416 
# F-statistic: 141.6 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 6.298e-16
```

### Edit

To elaborate on my comment, we can extract the desired values very easily doing

```
by(iris, iris$Species, \(x) lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, x)) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    with(summary(x), c(r2=r.squared, f=fstatistic, 
                       p=do.call(pf, c(as.list(unname(fstatistic)), lower.tail=FALSE))))
  }) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#                    r2    f.value f.numdf f.dendf            p
# setosa     0.07138289   3.689765       1      48 6.069778e-02
# versicolor 0.56858983  63.263024       1      48 2.586190e-10
# virginica  0.74688439 141.636664       1      48 6.297786e-16
```

Comment: It's worked very well, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @ArthurFilipedaSilva Removing the `summary` from the function to get a list of `"lm"` objects might be more flexible, i.e. just `lm_lst <- by(., lm(.))`. You can do anything you want with it in a second step, e.g. `lapply(lm_lst, summary)`, `lapply(lm_lst, confint)`, .... Cheers!

Comment: @ArthurFilipedaSilva Please see update on how to extract only the desired values. See source code of `stats:::print.summary.lm` for p value calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to pull out those values, we can use

```
library (dplyr) 

df <- iris

list_res <- df %>%
  base::split (., df$Species, drop = FALSE) %>%
  lapply (., function (x) {
   fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = x) %>%
      summary ()
   r <- fit$r.squared
   coeffs <- fit$coefficients %>% 
     as_tibble ()
   f <- fit$fstatistic[[1]] 
   list_res <- list (r, coeffs, f)
   names (list_res) <- c("R-Squared", "Coefficients", "F-Value")
   return (list_res)
  })
```

That returns a list of three objects for each regression model including the desired values. I've left the coefficients table here as it is, since it's always good to know to which independent variable your p-values belong. If you want those p-values pulled out separately, we can use `coeffs <- fit$coefficients [,4] %>% as.list ()`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! I runned the code here, but it don't worked, and R returned this message: "Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name." Do you have a clue what it mean?

Comment: I think that was because of df$Species whereas I've used the df's original name before. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Now it worked, much obliged!